# Responsive Embedded Background Video full screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, fullscreen, embedded-video

I'm using Bootstrap and was wondering if you could embed a video as background but filling the whole screen, just the same you'd do with an image, centering it when resizing but always full screen.

I express myself very badly so I've prepared [this](http://jsfiddle.net/s8s735bd) so that you see what I want to get.

Now, I'm trying to do the same with an [embedded video](http://jsfiddle.net/s8s735bd/1), but I don't know how to do it.

**HTML**

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <div id="background">
       <iframe id='player' width="2500" height="1406" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rk6_hdRtJOE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=Rk6_hdRtJOE&amp;enablejsapi=1&version=3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
</div>          
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#background {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I'd like to get something like [this](http://demosthenes.info/samples/polina.html). When you resize the window, the video is adapted to fill the screen no matter horizontally it only appears part of the video. That's been done with the 'video' tag, I'm using the 'iframe' one.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it thanks to [tubular](http://www.seanmccambridge.com/tubular/).

You just need to add in your body a div tag with the id "wrapper" and call their function in js:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$().ready(function() {
  $('#wrapper').tubular({videoId: 'idOfYourVideo'}); // where idOfYourVideo is the YouTube ID.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

test this way.

**HTML**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
        <div id="background">
           <iframe id='player' width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Rk6_hdRtJOE?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;playlist=Rk6_hdRtJOE&amp;enablejsapi=1&version=3" frameborder="0"></iframe>
        </div>
    </div>          
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body{ height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
#background {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index: -999;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.container-fluid{margin: 0; padding: 0; height: 100%;}
.embed-responsive{height: 100%;}
```

Comment: It's completely the same. Try it in jsfiddle, copy your code and you'll see. Thanks for the try, though.

Comment: what I want is when you resize, as the pixels of the video and the window don't have be the same, the video must be shown partly in its width but always 100% height.

Comment: Cool this Tubular! The example that i posted was not the same http://jsfiddle.net/m86kndsx/ this is your http://jsfiddle.net/0e89mjLp/
There's a problem because of the black bar at the top and bottom due to the resolution of the video. But now i understand you wanted, the content of video with height 100%.

Comment: ...really, content of video full screen